# jq fromdate "does not match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"

Tags: json, jq, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I have an example json output below, the `LastAccessedDate` value is as AWS outputs it when running CLI command and thus I have no control over the format of the date.

```
{
  "MyList": [
    {
      "Name": "MyName1",
      "LastAccessedDate": "2021-06-29T02:00:00+02:00"
    }
  ]
    
}
```

When trying to run a jq command to select using `fromdate` like this:

`cat output.json | jq '.[] | .[] | select ( .LastAccessedDate | fromdate > "2021-01-01T02:00:00+02:00")'`

then I get the error message:
`jq: error (at <stdin>:8): date "2021-06-29T02:00:00+02:00" does not match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`

Is there anything I could do to enable me to use jq to filter the output?
Would even appreciate an explanation on what may be wrong so that I can understand for future use cases.

Comment: `jq` does not support parsing time strings with timezones (natively) yet. i.e. with +/- offsets. You need to write your own

Comment: BTW, note that it's better to avoid `cat output.json | jq ...` -- instead of starting a separate `/bin/cat` execution and making `jq` read from a FIFO attached to that program's output, use `jq ... <output.json` so `jq` can read direct from the file, instead of needing to read from the output of _a separate executable_ that's reading from the file. For jq specifically it's not such a huge difference in practice, but there are other standard tools where the performance difference is huge.

Comment: (for example, `cat file | wc -c` is O(n) since it needs to read every byte of `file` before it knows how large the file is; but `wc -c <file` is O(1) since no matter the size of file, it can do a `seek()` call to jump to the end and a `tell()` call to get its current position).

Comment: `strptime("%FT%T%z")` could be an option, though it requires timezones like `+0200` rather than `+02:00`.

Comment: However, assuming the timestamps *are* in the same timezone and in the same format, you can compare them lexicographically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use a custom function to strip off the timezone part and format the date string to a format compatible that `jq` can parse.

Note that this **only** works when your reference and source strings are in the same timezone offset.

```sh
jq --arg ref "2021-01-01T02:00:00+02:00" '
  def c(str): str | (split("+")[0] + "Z") | fromdate ; 
  .MyList | map(select( c(.LastAccessedDate) > c($ref) ))' json
```

From jq Manual

> The `fromdate` builtin parses datetime strings. Currently `fromdate` only supports **ISO 8601 datetime** strings, but in the future it will attempt to parse datetime strings in more formats.

Comment: Note, though, that `c` produces a timestamp different from its input. That's fine both arguments were in the same timezone originally, but will cause problems otherwise.

Comment: @chepner: Yes added a note about it

Comment: The wording of the manual is also unfortunate, as the requirement for `Z` means `jq` only parses a *subset* of valid ISO 8601 datetimes.

Comment: 1) `2021-01-01T02:00:00+02:00` is a valid ISO 8601 timestamp. (Also valid RFC 3339, which is far more restrictive than ISO 8601.) 2) Your solution only works if all time stamps have the same offset, which it probably *doesn't* around a DST change.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a jq function for converting certain ISO 8601 timestamps with timezone offsets to seconds since the beginning of the Epoch, thus facilitating comparisons of timestamps with different offsets.

```
# Convert a timestamp with a possibly empty timezone offset to seconds since the Epoch.
# Input should be a string of the form 
# yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss or yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss<OFFSET>
# where <OFFSET> is Z, or has the form `+hh:mm` or `-hh:mm`.
# If no timezone offset is explicitly given, it is taken to be Z.
def datetime_to_seconds:
  if test("[-+]")
  then capture("(?<datetime>^.*T[0-9:]+)(?<s>[-+])(?<hh>[0-9]+):?(?<mm>[0-9]*)")
  | (.datetime +"Z" | fromdateiso8601) as $seconds
  | (if .s == "+" then -1 else 1 end) as $plusminus
  | ([.hh,.mm] | map(tonumber) |.[0] *= 60 | add * 60 * $plusminus) as $offset
  | ($seconds + $offset)
  else . + (if test("Z") then "" else "Z" end) | fromdateiso8601
  end;
```

Note that the interpretation of `+` or `-` in the offset conforms with the principle encapsulated in the example:

> The following times all refer to the same moment: "18:30Z", "22:30+04", "1130−0700", and "15:00−03:30".